# How to hide form by mouse click beyond the form area withou JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I've the follwoing form:

```
<form method="get">
<!-- This is form's content -->
</form>
```

I want to hide the form by mouse click beyond the form area. I'm trying to set `window.onclick` event handler but this handler is override others onlcick handler on my page. I need to do this **WITHOUT JQUERY**. Thanks.

Comment: 1. Show an attempt. 2. It will be easier to give the form an ID

Comment: [addEventListener](http://mdn.beonex.com/en/DOM/element.addEventListener.html), and [HTMLElement.style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.style) or [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give your form an Id and add use `e.target.id` in [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener):

```
<form method="get" id="myform">
<!-- This is form's content -->
Dummy content
</form>
<script>
    window.onclick = function(e) {
        alert('other handlers');
    }
    window.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        if (e.target.id != "myform") {
            document.getElementById('myform').style.display = 'none';
        }
    });
</script>
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6bewY/

Comment: he said beyond the form area

Comment: I want to hide the form by click **beyond** the form's area.

Comment: window.onclick is override others onclick handlers

Comment: @DmitryFucintv I am sorry, I have updated my answer. Check it out.

Comment: Thanks, I'm understand you now.